# Windows Batch file to create MySQL dump adding variable

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I have created the following windows batch file `backup.bat`:

```
cls
mysqldump -u root -p my_database_name > BACKUP.sql
```

My problem is that batch create the same file in the same path that it has been run from. I want to add some timestamp or date to the file name `BACKUP.sql` to be something like `BACKUP_2330255555588.sql` to make different files in the same place.

Another side: for restore I need a batch file that prompt input for the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following snippets:

Backup file:

```
SET backupPath="C:\backups\"
FOR /F "TOKENS=2-4 DELIMS=/ " %A IN ('DATE /T') DO SET date=%%C-%%A-%%B
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/: " %a in ('echo %time%') do (set mytime=%a-%b-%c-%d)
SET timestamp=%date%_%mytime%
mysqldump -u ROOT --password=PASS my_database_name > "%backupPath%BACKUP%timestamp%.sql"
```

Recovery file with prompt:

```
@echo off
echo "Running backup script"
set /p BackupFilePath= Enter the recovery file path? 
@echo on
mysql -u ROOT --password=PASS my_database_name<%BackupFilePath%
```

Bru

Comment: There is another issue, if there is some error in mysqldump, it write an corrupted file. I need to know how to make the batch file recognize that error and delete the file.